# Chrome and IE not sending ASP.NET_SessionID - i.e. session variable gets lost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-state, session-variables, session-cookies

I have an ASP NET MVC 3 app with a page with some paramater being set (let say `region`='North').

When this get posted back to server, I set this parameter as a session variable and return three images having their `src` attribute set to three different `controller/getImageXy` urls.

Now, these controller methods execute a query (based on a session variable) and return images.
It's kinda neat, user gets a quick reply and then those images get populated (asynchronously).

Everything works fine in FF. The initial reply has a **`ASP`.`NET_SessionID`** set (cookie).

FF, then, GETs three images, with the same cookie, and everything is fine.

Chrome and IE, however, don't.

They're just sending `__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__`. 
Naturally, my session variable ("`region`") gets lost.

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: Are you using an IFrame? I had a recent issue similar to this, but it only presented itself in IE and Chrome when an IFrame was involved.

Comment: No, it's pretty much a body tag with three img tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question and probably save someone few hours:

The problem was that I was setting the `domain` attribute on session id cookie.

Why did I do that? 
I copied it from the book "Proffesional ASP NET MVC 3", page 163, having the intention to set the `HttpOnly` flag. Quote:

> You can stop script access to all cookies in your site by adding a
>   simple flag: HttpOnly. You can set  this in the web.config like so:
>
> `<httpCookies domain=”String” httpOnlyCookies=”true” requireSSL=”false”/>`

I was punished for copy pasting without thinking.
So, when I changed this to  `domain=""`, the issue was fixed.

Interestingly, FF was ignoring (or misusing) this attribute, but that is another topic.